# AWS S3 public_access_block wipes cors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I want to create s3 bucket to serve openapi specs. I observe strange behavior. When aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block included cors and aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration doesn't apply. And even if I comment it out, deploy everything else then add access_block, it wipes cors, permissions and website.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "openapi_ui_bucket" {
  bucket        = var.bucket_name
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "openapi_ui_bucket_public_access" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.openapi_ui_bucket.id

  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "openapi_ui_bucket_website" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.openapi_ui_bucket.id
  index_document {
    suffix = "index.html"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_cors_configuration" "openapi_ui_bucket_cors" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.openapi_ui_bucket.id

  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = ["*"]
    allowed_methods = ["GET", "POST"]
    allowed_origins = ["${var.openapi_domain}/"]
    expose_headers  = []
    max_age_seconds = 3000
  }
}
```